# How can I replace my existing .Net Socket Server with WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, sockets

I am currently working in socket based technology where my client(C++) and Server(.Net) uses
socket based communication to send and receive data,but now I am looking to replace my existing socket server with WCF. I want to clarify it completely before doing any such movement

1) Is it possible to replace existing socket and if yes how can I do this.
2) Server socket application listen at defined IP/Port and client socket application send request to that IP/Port only, but in case of WCF there is complete URI i.e. with IP/Port it also contains name of WCF Service, so how to do this.
3) Which type of binding configuration I need to use for it and if it is basic or wshttp can't it will effect performance of my application drastically.

Comment: Hey anyone can please answer to my question. I believe that my question is understandable.

Comment: WCF has quite a steep learning curve. I would start by reading - anything by `Juval Lowy` or `Julia Lerman` would be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we use socket programming we do it at very low level and neither wcf, web service or remoting can perform good as compare to socket application. WCF provides so many feature but all this features are based on binding configuration and all this are at very high level as compare to socket application, so as far as performance is concern socket application will perform well as compare to wcf and if this are already build no need to replace it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather difficult one to answer without knowing all the details of your application so I am going to attempt to answer this in a different order than you have asked it.

2) WCF supports [multiple transport configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms729350.aspx).  These are not limited to HTTP.  For instance, the net.tcp transport doesn't use http at all but it does implement some complex functionality which you would need to replicate on the client side. For example [Message Framing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc219293.aspx).  This limits you choices to one of the standards-based approaches (unless you like doing that stuff).

3) Yes the http transports will probably be slower than direct socket communication.  You will need need to profile exactly what features you require from WCF and what performance you need as there are many different configuration options which can have an impact on this.

1)  So I guess this is the main answer.  Yes it is possible but you will be required to make changes on both the client and server.  While it is potentially possible for you to extend WCF to support your existing socket messaging format this could be a difficult and costly development process.  Therefore you would want to implement this using Web Services (aka one of the http bindings) as opposed to net.tcp, msmq, etc.

Please note that WCF is actually extremely configurable with each layer having the ability to define custom transports, messaging, security, etc, etc.  I would therefore suggest you read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733103.aspx)